# Do php's strip_tag function consider a string with two underlines a constructor?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, strip-tags

I'm using PHP's `strip_tag` function in a WordPress project, and it works just ok, except when a link that contains two underlines 
(**for example:** `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS7e1__lyn4`) comes in. When the link comes in, it returns empty. Is there a way to tell `strip_tag` to ignore two underlines?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://3v4l.org/MoeXt

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [documentation](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)?

There's no reason for **strip_tags()** to break with the two underlines "__" in the text or tag.

A possible fix in your instance (if you want to keep the href) is to set the *second parameter* to strip_tags() that would allow you to set permitted tags:

```
$my_string = 'This is a string <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS7e1__lyn4">My Link</a>';

echo strip_tags($my_string, "<a>");
```

Also make sure that you are indeed sending a **valid string** to the strip_tags function. This can seem trivial, but people make mistakes.